# Flutter: Como hacer para que la aplicaicon inicie de una vez sin pedir los permisos de localizacion

Tags: android, google-maps, flutter

Necesito ayuda con esto, quisiera saber si existe alguna manera de saltar este paso, y otorgarles los permisos a la aplicación de una vez y no aparezca esta ventana 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por temas de seguridad, a partir de Android 6.0+ es necesario solicitar permisos en tiempo de ejecución. https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es importante comentar que desde **Android 6.0+ algunos [permisos considerados "peligrosos"](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/requesting.html#normal-dangerous), deben ser requeridos y confirmados por parte del usuario.**

El usuario que instala la aplicación determina determina aceptarlos y queda en el la responsabilidad de la ejecución de los mismos en su dispositivo por parte de la aplicación.

En este caso los permisos de ubicación ([Location](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview#normal-dangerous)) se encuentran dentro del grupo de permisos a requerir manualmente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es importante aclarar que **no es posible bloquear la petición de estos permisos desde una aplicación Android.**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Puedes evitar que el diálogo los vuelva a requerir, sin embargo esto puede causar que tu aplicación no funcione adecuadamente.